# Troubleshooting linux server reboots?

Tags: linux, debian, troubleshooting

I have a Linux server I've just set up, debian squeeze, 2.6.32-5-amd64, and over the past week it's rebooted three times, twice in one day. There was no power outage that I am aware of (and it's running on a UPS), and there are no errors in syslog, besides a few to-be-expected ones on bootup to do with clearing out entries in the ext4 journal due to the unclean shutdown.

What steps can I take to determine the cause of the reboots? Is there a way to get it to hang instead of rebooting, so I can copy stack traces or something off the screen? Any way to increase debug messages, or get it to dump things to disk, or something?

Answer (score 2):

That may be some hardware problem; the most common are failed RAM and overheating. You could install `mbmon` to monitor motherboard and CPU temperature; and run`memtest86+` to check your RAM and CPU cache.

Comment: mbmon gives "No Hardware Monitor found" but after upgrading my kernel, lm-sensors gives CPU core temperature now, which seems reasonable (average around 35 C, goes up to 55C if I run a benchmark on all cores). Will try memtest when I figure out how to run it on a remote server.

Comment: You can't run it directly on a remote server, but there's a linux equivalent you may run without rebooting (though it's not as thorough): memtester.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance it is a 'kernel panic' and a kernel 'oops' message is sent to the console before the reboot. The kernel can be configured to reboot on 'panic' or to stay on. Check:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/panic
```

If it is non-zero try putting 0 there (you can do it directly writting to the file, via /etc/sysctl.conf which is usually parsed on boot, or using the `sysctl` utility), this should stop rebooting. If it is already 0, then the reboots are not caused by kernel panics.

Comment: It's 0...so must be something else then. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `last`.  Look for reboot.  Try to correlate that with who was logged in if anyone and who has superuser privileges.  If it is not a user, you may have power/heat issues or some type of kernel panic causing issues.  Try to rule those out one by one.

Comment: Nobody else but me logging in (double checked the IP even from last). It's on an UPS, so I don't think it's a power issue, unless the server power supply is failing. I don't think it's heat issues, at least the server is not heavily loaded, and the current temperature is quite low (CPU at 36C), I'll start logging the temperature though.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to dump the kernel panic to disk or to screen? I'm worried that it's just rebooting and not saving the error messages anywhere. Is there a 'debug mode' or something I can enable?

Comment: A kernel panic is very unlikely - hardware trouble such as an overheating processor or memory errors is much more likely.

Comment: how to verify that? I have the same problem but I need to convince my provider that something is hardware? Too much reboot may be a software issue.